# Android - RecyclerView - Scrolling to specific textview

Tags: android

In my application, I want to scroll to a specific TextView in a RecyclerView if an intent specifies to scroll there. The original implementation involved looking at a listView, and looking at each item in it until I found a string matching the expected TextView string. I'm not sure how to replicate this for a RecyclerView. The closest I got to it was to look at the PreferenceGroupAdapter, but it seems to be a restricted class.

Comment: What is your data inside your adapter? String, Objects?

Comment: PreferenceGroupAdapter is an android adapter that connects a RecyclerView to Preference objects. Barring this, the only adapter I can use is the normal Adapter.

Answer (score 3):

Create a method that returns the position of that `TextView` within your adapter. For this example, I created a very simple `RecyclerView.Adapter` that just holds a `List<String> items` and is looking for the string `"target"`.

```
private int getTargetPosition(RecyclerView recycler) {
    MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter) recycler.getAdapter();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.items.size(); i++) {
        if (adapter.items.get(i).equals("target")) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    throw new AssertionError("target is guaranteed to be in the list");
}
```

After that, it's as easy as calling `scrollToPosition()`:

```
int position = getTargetPosition(recycler);
recycler.scrollToPosition(position);
```